# Get Model Binding Path From Tree Item on Select

Tags: sapui5

I'm using sap.m.Tree with JSON model. On the tree item select, I would like to see the path in the model.

I have made an [example](https://jsbin.com/gadonec/edit?html,console,output) with a tree and callback for `itemPress` event:

```
var oTree = new sap.m.Tree("tree", {
  itemPress: function(oEvent) {
    console.log("itemPress event =", oEvent);
    var items = oEvent.getParameter("listItem");
    console.log("parameters", items);
  }
});
```

I guess I should get path from the model from `oEvent` parameter but can't see anything helpful as I inspect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the binding path from the bound context of the pressed item:

```
oEvent.getParameter("listItem").getBindingContext(/*modelName*/).getPath()
```

## API References

- [`getBindingContext`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/methods/getBindingContext)
- [`getPath`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Context/methods/getPath)

Comment: I don't know how to set a model name. The ' oTree.setModel(oModel, "nodes")` results into an empty tree and there is no error.

Comment: @AljaMrakTadel If you pass a model name to [setModel](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/methods/setModel), you'll need to update all the relevant binding paths as well since a control can contain multiple models. By this, the framework can know from which model it has to retrieve the data. E.g. in case of `.setModel(oModel, "myModelName")`: `oTree.bindItems("myModelName>/", oStandardTreeItem)` and `title: "{myModelName>text}"`, etc..

Comment: @AljaMrakTadel But since you didn't pass any model name, there is no need to change the binding paths everywhere. In this case, just call `oEvent.getParameter("listItem").getBindingContext().getPath()` to get the binding path of the pressed item.